# my action path in expressionengine search form has wrong value

Tags: expressionengine

I used EE ver 2.10 also use simple search tag like this:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="magazine-posts" result_page="/results"}
   <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" autocomplete="off"/>  
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

but redirect to `index.php` to show results. when I check HTML code in inspect element, I see form action path is: `action="http://example.com/index.php` that is wrong.

please help to resolve it.

Comment: first: why do you have result_page="/results" when you redirect to the homepage from that template? you could do result_page="/" just as easy
second, Are you sure you have removed all mentions of "index.php" in the config file and channel and search settings?